# Salesforce retrieve() via Apex

Tags: apex, retrieve

As per the documentation of [salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_retrieve.htm), One can use `retrieve()` to retrieve one or more records based on the specified IDs.

This is the syntax-based of the above reference document.

```
sObject[] result = connection.retrieve(string fieldList, string sObjectType, ID ids[]);
```

What is this `connection` mean here? I tried the following syntax with no luck

```
List<String> listIds = new List<String>{'a0H3l00000PE9PMEA1'};
sObject[] result = Database.retrieve('ID, Name', 'Account', listIds);
```

And received the following error

> COMPILE ERROR: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void
> retrieve(String, String, List) from the type Database LINE: 2
> COLUMN: 29

What am I missing here?

Comment: The doc example you're looking at is for java and related to the SOAP API. What are you trying to accomplish? If it's just a query, in apex, you can do [SOQL queries](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_soql).

Comment: Definitely SOQL is the first choice to retrieve records in apex, but I am looking for some other syntax.

Answer (score 2):

This API unfortunately doesn't exist in Apex. You can call the REST API to get at this data, but it requires a callout. This [has been asked for before but closed due to low activity](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdY7GUAV/apex-code-retrieve-and-databaseretrieve-to-mirror-soap-api). Unfortunately, you'll have to build your own queries.